# Rate constants and their relationship to quantum yields

Tags: physical-chemistry, photochemistry, dye

#### Question

> A dye molecule has a singlet excited state lifetime of $\pu{0.85 ns}.$ The
>   quantum yield of triplet formation is $35~\%.$ What is the rate constant for
>   intersystem crossing from the singlet to the triplet excited state?

#### Solution

> $$\mathrm{QY} = \tau_\mathrm{isc}/\tau_0 = 0.35 = \tau_\mathrm{isc}/0.85$$
>   Therefore
>   $$\tau_\mathrm{isc} = 0.35 × 0.85 × 10^{-9} = \pu{0.297E-9} = \pu{0.3E-9}$$
>   But $k_\mathrm{isc} = 1/\tau_\mathrm{isc}.$
>   So, $k_\mathrm{isc} = \pu{3.3E9 s-1}$

#### My working

$$\phi_{T} = \frac{k_\mathrm{isc}}{k_0} = \frac{\tau_0}{\tau_\mathrm{isc}}$$

and then substituting the values

$$0.35 = \frac{0.85}{\tau_\mathrm{isc}},$$

hence

$$\tau_\mathrm{isc} = \frac{0.85}{0.35} = \pu{2.43 ns},$$

so

$$k_\mathrm{isc} = \frac{1}{\tau_\mathrm{isc}} = \frac{1}{\pu{2.43E-9}} = \pu{4.11E8 s-1}.$$

But apparently in the solution the quantum yield $\displaystyle\phi_T = \frac{\tau_\mathrm{isc}}{\tau_{0}}$ and then the working follows as above to yield $k_\mathrm{isc} = \pu{3.3E9 s-1}.$

Am I mistaken or is the solution mistaken?

Comment: Looks like the solution is mistaken. Not sure what else there is to say about this, really...

Comment: I agree. The solution is mistaken, at least in the calculation of the tau for intercrossing.

Comment: Your answer is the correct one.